# How to make two or more columns to be unique in PHPMyAdmin?

Tags: phpmyadmin

I am having a table - Appointment.
Columns: ID, Date, Time, Doctor_Assigned

What I am trying to prevent:

> ID = 1, Date = 1/1/2017, Time = 3pm, Doctor_Assigned = DoctorA
>
> ID = 2, Date = 1/1/2017, Time = 3pm, Doctor_Assigned = DoctorA

Column Date, Time and Doctor_Assigned should not be the same for 2 rows of data.

What I want:

> ID = 1, Date = 1/1/2017, Time = 3pm, Doctor_Assigned = **DoctorA**
>
> ID = 2, Date = 1/1/2017, Time = 3pm, Doctor_Assigned = **DoctorB**

Same date and time, different Doctor or vice versa.

I know there's a unique button to set for a column but not two or more columns.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UNIQUE(Date, Time, Doctor_Assigned)
```

Let's assume you want `ID` to be Primary Key and for the rest of them, you don't want them to repeat as a set, then you can use this :

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    ID int(4) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Date varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    Time varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    Doctor_Assigned varchar(255) NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY (ID),
    UNIQUE(Date, Time, Doctor_Assigned)

) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

This makes Date, Time, Doctor_Assigned Unique as a set.

Comment: Thank you so much! I thought `UNIQUE(Date, Time, Doctor_Assigned)` is to make each columns unique without being a set.

Comment: Anytime @Renzo!